# How do I add followup questions as s button in dialogeflow chatbot?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to learn chatbot development in Dialugeflow.

I see how to add follow up, intents, entity. But no luck to add followups like this snapshot

[image]

I checked various articles, youtube video and gothrough dialogueflow documentation. But still no luck

Any reference document will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Go to any one of the intents which you have created.
Step 2: Go to responses and add Google Assistant there. (You can do this by clicking + symbol which is beside of default)
Step 3: Now click Add Responses. You will find few options there. Now select Suggestion chips and now you can add your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Divya, thanks for giving input to the question. Sadly your answer provides a suggestion chip for Google Assistant responses, this doesnt answer the OP's question. The OP doesnt seem to be using Google Assistant or asking for Google Assistant input at this time. If you need more help with answering questions, please see the help section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer